# Get single-page website below navigation bar on bottom of browser

Tags: html, css, navbar

Okay, so the title might sound confusing, I'm not sure. I've got a site I'm working on locally and I have the navigation bar start at the bottom of the page and then scroll up and become fixed to the top of the browser. The issue I'm having, however, is getting my `#pageContent` to go below the navigation bar. It's taking up the space both above *and* below it. Please take a look at the CodePen I've linked below to see what I mean.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGVmvx

**Note 1:** The IDs of what I'm trying to get below my navigation bar are `#pageContent` and `#pageContentWrapper`. They can be found at the very bottom of my CSS and are what contains all of the `<br /><br />` in my HTML. If I'm thinking correctly the focus should be on getting `#pageContent` below the navbar (since it's what contains `#pageContentWrapper`.

**Note 2:** While they're taking up the space above my navbar, they're covering the landing (or home) section of the website. If you comment out the background colors you'll be able to see it.

**Note 3:** I only gave them the backgrounds I did so it's easier on you guys visually and you can tell the sections you're working with apart from the rest. Once they're below the navigation bar the background will be switched to white (for both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is simpler since `div#pageContent` has a position of value absolute. Give it a CSS property of `top:%100`

```
div#pageContent {
  background: #d35400;  /* Set this to #fff once you get it where the page content is below the navbar like it should be */
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  top:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had honestly thought about that but was afraid it might cause issues later on or on a different sized device or something. (^_^;)